# Facets: organising their order and organising the levels within facets

Tags: r

I would like to please organise the following plots so that facets are printed out from most to least busy (i.e. Hemiptera, Coleoptera, Hymenoptera, Siphonaptera, Lepidoptera, etc.)

I would also like to order the levels within each facet like in Coleoptera. I realise that the X-labels will change order too so I need each facet to print out its own X-label according the level order.

I have already read many threads and that's how I was able to organise Coleoptera. But now I want it to be more tidy.

This is the data (let me know if this format is ok, if not I can try another way):

```html
structure(list(Order = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), .Label = c("Coleoptera", 
"Dermaptera", "Dictyoptera", "Diptera", "Hemiptera", "Hymenoptera", 
"Lepidoptera", "Phthiraptera", "Psocoptera", "Siphonaptera", 
"Thysanoptera"), class = "factor"), Nrange = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 14L, NA, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 14L, NA, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 14L, 15L, NA, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 4L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 4L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 1L, 5L, 10L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 14L), .Label = c("Africa", 
"Africa, Asia", "Americas", "Asia", "Asia-Temp", "Asia-Trop", 
"Australasia", "C&S America", "Cosmopolitan", "Cryptogenic", 
"N America", "S America", "Trop", "Trop, SubTrop", "Unknown"), class = "factor"), 
    Records = c(16L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 11L, 17L, 1L, 15L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 11L, 
    10L, 30L, 15L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 34L, 11L, 21L, 1L, 21L, 16L, 
    8L, 1L, 14L, 3L, 5L, 25L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L)), .Names = c("Order", "Nrange", "Records"), row.names = c(NA, 
-83L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "Order", drop = TRUE)
```

This is the reordering that I guess is affecting only Coleoptera.

```css
xy<-x%>%
  mutate(Nrange=reorder(Nrange,-Records,sum))
```

This is the plot:

```css
to_plot<-xy %>%
  filter(!is.na(Nrange))
ggplot(to_plot,aes(x=Nrange,y=Records,fill=Nrange))+
geom_col()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.7), legend.position = "none") +
  facet_wrap(~Order,ncol=3)+
  labs(title="Insects recorded as alien-invasive to mainland Spain", 
       subtitle="Native ranges vs number of records", 
       caption="Data source: DAISIE (http://www.europe-aliens.org/)")
```

And this is the plot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqKvo.jpg)

Comment: Please provide a reproducible dataset on which we can run your code.

Comment: Based on your code, I'm guessing you already have the `tidyverse` packages installed. If so, have a look at the `forcats` package, particularly the `fct_reorder` function. Also, the chapter on factors in R for Data Science.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the `tidyverse` (based on your code):

```
library(tidyverse)

xy <- x %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    Order = fct_reorder(Order, Records, sum, .desc = TRUE)
  )

xy %>%
  filter(!is.na(Nrange)) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x = Nrange, y = Records, fill = Nrange) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~Order, ncol = 3)
```

`fct_reorder` comes from the `forcats` package, which I believe is now a part of the `tidyverse`.

Or, using base R, something like this:

```
xy <- x
record_sums <- tapply(xy$Records, xy$Order, sum)
levels(xy$Order) <- levels(xy$Order)[order(record_sums, decreasing = TRUE)]
```

Comment: Hi @Alexey! Thank you so much. The code reorganised the way facets were printed in descending order.

Comment: Great! If the answer was correct, please mark it as answered (the grey check mark) and, if you'd like, give it an up vote, so I can get those sweet Stack Overflow points ;)

Comment: HI Alexey! I tried to press the up vote but it says that I have less than 15 points reputation and "it's recorded but will not be displayed." :D

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks anyway! Marking the question as answered is the main thing anyway.